# Plotting cubes on 3d axes

Tags: 3d, ilnumerics

I am new to ILNumerics and 3d plotting.

I need to construct pyramidal cubes that have a 3d rotation.

I need solid Cubes having a specific color on the co-ordinate axes.  Can someone kindly provide me the code?

I have tried with `Shapes.unitCubeFilled` and added it to scene, but that does not let me specify the co-ordinates of the corner points of the cube.

I have created scale modes and set it to Linear.

I have tried to explore on Surfaces in ILnumerics but i don't think that will help.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

You can use any shape (like Shapes.unitCubeFilled) and translate them arbitrarily. Place the shape below a new ILGroup node. Groups provide the Tranlate() and Scale() methods which allow you to move all the objects contained within to their intended position.

Some links:

Transformations on group nodes: 
http://ilnumerics.net/scene-graph-group-nodes-transformations.html

Class reference fo ILGroup: 
http://ilnumerics.net/apidoc/?topic=html/T_ILNumerics_Drawing_ILGroup.htm